# C# convert Bitmap to RichTextBox Rtf

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, richtextbox

What is the simplest way to convert an image to Rtf? I would like do somethink like this:

```
rtb.AppendText(":P");
rtb.Rtf = ConvertSmileys(rtb.Rtf);
```

In convert smileys method I'd like check for smileys and call some method like this:

```
rtb.Rtf.Replace(":P", ConvertImageToRtf(new Bitmap("mySmiley.png"));
```

But I don't know how to convert image to rtf format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the RTF specification for pictures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140283(v=office.10).aspx#rtfspec_24